# Turn shortcode into link

Tags: html, shortcode

Is it possible to make this shortcode into a clickable link? I have a link for a button, but I want the complete box to be the link

```
[infobox color="#dd3333" textcolor="#ffffff" icon="arrow-circle-o-right"][/infobox]
```

Can I not wrap it within an a tag?

```
   <a [infobox color="#dd3333" textcolor="#ffffff" icon="arrow-circle-o-right"][/infobox]</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, you just need to do it with the correct syntax. For example, your would be:

```
<a href="yourlink.html"> [infobox color="#dd3333" textcolor="#ffffff" icon="arrow-circle-o-right"]       [/infobox]</a>
```

And that's it. 
Have faith in your endevours!